# Switching characters in a list for different numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to switch out characters in a list for other characters with a given position in that list. For ex. 
`["*","*","*","*","*",.....]`, change the characters in position `[1,3,4,.....]`
with a given letter, for example X.

So `["*","*","*","*","*","*"]` becomes `["*",X,"*",X,X,"*"]`.

I've tried with this:

```
def test():
letter="a"
secret="*****"
secret2=list(secret)
pos=[1,3]
y = 1
x = pos[y]
flag = 0
while flag < 2:
    secret2[x]=letter
    flag = (flag + 1)
    y = (y+1)
return secret2
```

But it only returns the list as `["*","*","*",A,"*"]`

How would i solve this? Would it be able to solve easier with a class? In that case, how would this class look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[1,3,6]
>>> li=["*","*","*","*","*",'*','*']
>>> ['X' if i in l else j for i,j in enumerate(li)]
['*', 'X', '*', 'X', '*', '*', 'X']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def substitute_at_positions(lst, positions, substitute):
  return [substitute if i in positions else lst[i] for i in xrange(len(lst))]

lst = ["","","","","","",""]
print lst
print substitute_at_positions(lst, {1,3,5}, "x")
```

prints

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', 'x', '', 'x', '', 'x', '']
```

Comment: @Karl I appreciate the thanks, but you should choose an answer and mark it accepted. And if I'm honest, I think you should go for Kasra's answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a regular visitor and don't know how things are done yet!